# How to dynamically assign throttle category to a build job in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In the build environment I am working with I have X number of client build jobs that need to be kicked by a master jenkinsfile.  In addition, I have Y number of branches.  Out of those Y branches, some subset of those are available to be used with those client build jobs.  So what I am trying to do is be able to dynamically assign a throttle category/label to the build jobs in the jenkins file.  To put it even simpler.  I'm just trying to be able to kick jobs and assign labels to them in order to limit how many jobs of a single label are running on a single node (but could be consumed by other nodes).

I have looked through the various plugins and what seems to be what I want is a combination of Node and Label Parameter and then the Throttle Concurrent Builds.  What I want to be able to do is to have the specific client freestyle jobs to have no knowledge of label or throttle category (so that I don't have to constantly update them as branches change and client projects are cloned).  So I figured I could do this dynamically in a jenkins file.  I feel like I'm close, its just not doing what I want.  Here is my current code:

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages{
    stage('Build Everything') {
        steps {
            script {
                def builds = [:]
                builds["server"] = {
                    build job: 'Test_Server', parameters: [
                        [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'NODE_NAME', label: 'justin_trunk'],
                        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'DEVROOT', value: env.DEVROOT],
                        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REQUESTED_REVISION', value: env.REQUESTED_REVISION]
                    ]
                }
                builds["client"] = {
                    build job: 'Test_Client', parameters: [
                        [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'NODE_NAME', label: 'justin_trunk'],
                        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'DEVROOT', value: env.DEVROOT],
                        [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'REQUESTED_REVISION', value: env.REQUESTED_REVISION]
                    ] 
                }
                throttle(['justin_trunk']) {
                    parallel builds
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

So this code "works" in that it kicks the builds using those labels.  In Jenkins global configuration I have a Throttle category called justin_trunk that has the label justin_trunk associated with it that is supposed to limit nodes to one concurrent run.  What happens with this code though is that it kicks both in parallel on the same machine.  This is explicitly what I am trying to avoid by assigning the throttle category.

I do know that this works if I attach the throttle category to the downstream jobs themselves, but this is what I am trying to avoid.  The categories and labels will change frequently over time and I don't want to have to edit changes in many places in order to get what I consider to be pretty simple throttling capabilities.